# Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types with Spring Boot Controller

Tags: java, spring, gradle, controller, spring-boot

I am working on a project that takes some user input and returns a graph file from that input. I'm using Spring Boot framework, so I have an Application.java with the main class, and a GraphController with @RequestParam for user input.
The class that creates the graph, OntologyGraph, has this in it:

```
public class OntologyGraph {

    // Set argument variables
    private String graphTitle;
    private String prefix;
    private String graphType;
    private String inputFile;

    public String graphmlString;  

    // create graphml
    public OntologyGraph(String graphTitle, String prefix, String type, 
        String inputFile) throws Exception {

        // Set content to given content
        this.graphTitle = graphTitle;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.type = type;
        this.inputFile = inputFile;

        // code to process input is here

        return graphmlString;
}
```

And then I have GraphController.java to get and input the args:

```
@RestController
public class GraphController {

    @RequestMapping("/graph")
    public OntologyGraph graph(@RequestParam(value="graphTitle", defaultValue="Title") String graphTitle,
        @RequestParam(value="prefix", defaultValue="Prefix") String prefix,
        @RequestParam(value="type", defaultValue="class") String type,
        @RequestParam(value="inputFile", defaultValue="/Users/Tauber/Documents/onto-graph/src/test/Core.ttl") String inputFile) {

        return new OntologyGraph(graphTitle, prefix, type, inputFile);
    }
}
```

So it accepts those four arguments. But, when I try to run it (it's a gradle build, so I use gradle bootRun), it returns this error...

```
    error: constructor OntologyGraph in class OntologyGraph cannot be applied to given types;
        return new OntologyGraph(graphTitle, prefix, type, inputFile);
               ^
  required: String
  found: String,String,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

So It seems like, for some reason, it's only accepting one argument?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is an error in your constructor:

```
public OntologyGraph(String graphTitle, String prefix, String type, 
    String inputFile) throws Exception {


    return graphmlString;
}
```

You are trying to return a string in your constructor, which shouldn't be possible in Java. Which then causes a compile error, I would guess.

Comment: What would you recommend to return the graphmlString for the GraphController? I've tried just setting graphmlString in the constructor, and getting it with something like public String getString() { return graphmlString; }, but I'm not sure how to get it as output in GraphController for localhost.

Comment: I would just overwrite the toString method or add a getter to access the build string.